# Why does the following result in "Must set Ember.set() to access this property"?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm attempting to filter the content of my documents controller according to the content of my selected tags controller. I'm not sure if this is the best solution so feel free to suggest an alternative.

Aside from that uncertainty, can anyone explain why the following results in `assertion failed: Must use Ember.set() to access this property`? Particularly `selectedTagsBinding: "App.selectedTagsController.content"` is what fails.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.documentsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [],

    selectedTagsBinding: "App.selectedTagsController.content" 
});

App.selectedTagsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [ new Ember.Object(), new Ember.Object() ]
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually this isn't a bug. You should be setting your controllers like this:

```
App.set('documentsController', Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
  selectedTagsBinding: "App.selectedTagsController" 
}));

App.set('selectedTagsController', Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
  content: [
      Ember.Object.create({
          name: "john"
      }), Ember.Object.create({
          name: "sal"
      })
  ]
}));
```

I wrote up a short blog post explaining your error in greater detail here: http://ud3323.github.com/2012/02/15/ember-controllers-and-the-runloop.html.

Comment: No problem. I actually have to catch myself from doing the same thing in my own code sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: as ud3323 stated in his answer, this is not a bug and this answer has been written prior to my knowledge of `App.set`

---

This is obviously a bug with bindings. Moving the declaration of the `App.selectedTagsController` before `App.documentsController` works.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.selectedTagsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [ new Ember.Object(), new Ember.Object() ]
});

App.documentsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [],

    selectedTagsBinding: "App.selectedTagsController.content" 
});
```